# JQuery and FancyBox : error on Edge only

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, microsoft-edge

I use JQuery-1.11.0.js and jquery.fancybox.js to display a popup. That's work well on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Edge.

I'm on Magento but I don't know if there is a link..

The error is strange :

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
jquery-1.11.0.min.js (4,21732)
```

I don't know what will could generate this type of error. Someone have an idea ?

EDIT :

When I use non minimize jquery, I get this :

```
ajax: function( url, options ) {
[...]
        try {
            state = 1;
            transport.send( requestHeaders, done );
        } catch ( e ) {

            // Propagate exception as error if not done
            if ( state < 2 ) {
                done( -1, e );

            // Simply rethrow otherwise
            } else {
                throw e; // <-- It's here I got the exception which contain "Expected ')'"
            }
        }
    }
```

The Ajax function is call by the jquery.fancybox.js in the "after load" while it return "success"..

Comment: is there any reason you don't use a more recent jQuery - even in the 1.x series, like 1.12.4?

Comment: I resumed a project that already have this version (1.11.0). This is a big project so I don't change the jquery version to avoid compatibity issues with other plugin.

Comment: so, you've tried the *minor version* update 1.12.4, and found it breaks things? how jQuery is that!!

Comment: I didn't change the jquery version. Before that work and now not. But the error display not help me to understand where the problem's origin is. What would generate this type of issue ?

Comment: `Before that work and now not` - I don't understand, this suggests you've made some change that broke your page in Edge - what change did you make? The problem seems to be that Edge can't deal with the code  `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` - which is why I suggested `1.12.4` - for debugging, use non-minified `jquery-1.11.0.js` to debug the problem

Comment: As you've posted ZERO code, and 1.11.0 actually DOES work in Edge, not much more anyone can do for you

Comment: I change lot of thing on my project, but i don't touch on jquery-1.11.0.js and jquery.fancybox.js. So I can't post code. My question was "What will could generate this type of error : Expected ')' on Edge only". I just need some tips to know where I had to search". I will try to change jquery version to see if that change something.

Comment: `I just need some tips to know where I had to search` start at line 4, column 21732 in `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` - then when you realise that's not very friendly code, try one of my suggestions, to use the non minified 1.11.0 and see if that helps

Comment: I follow your advice (use jquery 1.12.4 and deminimize the file) and I put the result in edit on my main post. Do you know what could generate this type of issue on Ajax between two jquery, only on edge ?

Comment: The issue isn't ajax. The issue is that edge can't even parse the code.  I think

Comment: What code could be parse by Firefox and Chrome without send warning or error and throw exception on Edge ? Do you have any idea ?